# Want to download the .APK build from Hockey APP through Jenkins, to run tests on the downloaded .APK build

Tags: java, android, git, jenkins, hockeyapp

I want to trigger a build in jenkins whenever a new build is uploaded on hockeyapp. I need to download the new apk in my automation project and run the automated testcases. The apk will be generated from a separate development project. Via HockeyApp plugin in jenkins i am giving  API Token but i am confuse about App file path because apk will generate from a different project and after downloading where will this apk file be saved ? somwhere on jenkins or at my local server. Any help would be appreciated. Many Thanks